# Removing index.php & 301 redirects

Tags: htaccess

I am using the following in my .htaccess file to remove index.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Removes index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

I need to redirect an old page to a new, existing page but I am getting strange results.

I added the following to the .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /Payment.aspx /clients/login
```

But the url it redirects to looks like this:

```
http://www.myurl.com/clients/login?/Payment.aspx
```

It is adding that extra query string to the end of the URL.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When people hit your `/Payment.aspx` path, will they sometimes be linked with a query string?

Also, for best results, try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)^/Payment.aspx https://www.full-domain.com/clients/login
```

... which I'm 99% sure won't work if you **do** have query strings when you hit that payment path.

What you really want is a `RewriteRule` and then just drop query strings.

```
RewriteRule ^payment\.aspx$ /clients/login? [L,R=301,NC]
```

The trailing question mark should strip off any original query strings. The flags set it for 301, Last, and NoCase (ignore upper vs lower case `payment.aspx` variations. If the question mark doesn't do it, add a `QSD` flag (query string drop). That flag (QSD), I think, was introduced somewhat recently in mod_rewrite, so it may not be available in older versions and less maintenanced servers.

Also, this is dangerously close to not being EE related, but since you posted your EE related rewrites, I figured it was just close enough :p

Comment: There will never be query strings. And thanks for the help for my close enough question! :)

Comment: Actually, none of those worked for me. The RedirectMatch gave me the same results. The RewriteRule as written gave me a page not found error and adding QSD gave me a server error.

Comment: LULZ, sorry I failed. That was off the top of my head; I'll jump on a test server and see if I can test an actual result.

Comment: What was your resulting URL from the `RewriteRule` ? I tested the exact code I dropped, and it redirected me from `http://test.server.ip.num/payment.aspx` to `http://test.server.ip.num/clients/login`. NOTE; I put the `RewriteRule` *before* the EE rewrite rules, just after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: I think it must have been the order. I moved it to the top and it works fine now. Thank you!!!